# Responsive menu gone on wordpress Responsive theme

Tags: menus, responsive

The responsive menu on my website is gone (homepage only). I am not sure what caused that and don't know how to fix it. Can you please help? I will really appreciate it. The website is http://www.loenne.info/ . Thank you very much.